# Netstat shows the same Foreign Address while connection is from different docker containers in swarm mode on AWS EC2

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been trying to figure out this issue for a while and can't pinpoint the actual cause.  This started from trying to run HDFS in docker swarm on AWS EC2.  The services start up correctly and the logs show that HDFS datanode is able to get the correct container IP (**XXX**: *you mean from the Swarm network, right?*) but when it tries to connect to the namenode the request contains an IP that is in the subnet but the host part is wrong.  I also noticed when doing netstat on the name node all the connections from datanodes show the same Foreign address with ec2.internal prostfix

```
[root@hdfs-namenode /]# netstat
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 hdfs-namenod:cslistener ip-10-0-255-10.ec:54714 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 hdfs-namenode:ssh       ip-10-0-255-10.ec:53178 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 hdfs-namenode:ssh       ip-10-0-255-10.ec:34606 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 hdfs-namenod:cslistener ip-10-0-255-10.ec:54548 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0     79 hdfs-namenod:cslistener ip-10-0-255-10.ec:59888 ESTABLISHED
Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
```

The swarm overlay network subnet is `10.0.255.0/24`. If I change the subnet the IP address is always has the right subnet but different last octet.

If you check the `netstat` output the ssh connection is coming from different containers on the same host.

When I add another ec2 instance as a worker I see the same issue. The datanodes that connect to the namenode would all have the same IP address. It would be the same subnet and a different last octet from the manager node. It seems like there is NATing on the host network but I can't find any information about it. This happens only in swarm mode and on AWS EC2. The swarm network works correctly when I try running it on my Mac.

I was looking into `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
[root@hdfs-namenode /]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
search ec2.internal
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

I am not sure if this configuration would effect the DNS resolution.

`netstat -n` shows the same Foreign Address but it is not correct

```
root@hdfs-namenode /]# netstat -n
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 10.0.255.3:9000         10.0.255.10:54714       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.255.3:22           10.0.255.10:53178       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.255.3:22           10.0.255.10:34606       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.255.3:9000         10.0.255.10:54548       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 10.0.255.3:9000         10.0.255.10:59888       ESTABLISHED
```

Hopefully this is the right forum to post this question. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and the EC2 instances are provisioned in the AWS default VPC with security group set to open all ports to that specific security group which opens inter-connectivity between the nodes.

To deploy the services I've used docker stack deploy providing the docker-compose.yml file with defined overlay network and each service was attached to that network

```
networks:
  data-net:
    driver: overlay

  hdfs-namenode:
    container_name: hdfs-namenode
    hostname: hdfs-namenode
    image: hdfs-namenode:latest
    networks:
    - data-net
    ports:
    - 9000:9000
    - 50070:50070
    - 50470:50470
    volumes:
    - ./data/hdfs-namenode:/opt/app/data/namenode
```

Let me know if any other information would help to reproduce this issues.

Comment: my experience with swarm in ec2 isn't gret either... maybe you're better off just using elastic container or AWS hadoop offerings, without creating your own swarm?

Comment: You didn't specify which distro you're using, didn't describe how network setup is done and you expect others to guess? There's nothing helping in reproducing your setup correctly in your question.

Comment: @poige Updated the information.

Comment: what about docker's command — how did you deploy the containers?

Comment: @poige Added the docker info.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, this is way more precise now. Although still there's a config only for name-node. I'd also suggest showing exact commands you were using for deploy on both name-node and date-node(s).